# Добавить приложение в автозапуск ОС из кода

Tags: java, windows, автозагрузка, автозапуск

Такое вообще возможно? 
Именно что бы из кода Java программы это делалось.
ОС Windows.

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы код запускался при загрузке копма?

Comment: @МишаКотор jar файлик, да

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Возможно, причем легко. Открываете системный реестр (вот так, например: [Read/write to Windows registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` - autorun только текущего пользователя, либо

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` - общий autorun (требует прав администратора),

и пишете туда строковую переменную с произвольным именем (например, "MyProggie_Autorun") и командой, которую надо выполнить, в качестве значения. В вашем случае командой запуска jar.

Answer (score 0):

один из вариантов это сделать сервис для jar-ника, например, с помощью [WinSW](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw)